# Android WebView remove cookies from specific domain

Tags: java, android, android-webview

How to remove cookies from WebView on specific domain?

Like this method when I want to remove all cookies.

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

To be specific, I want to delete all .facebook.com cookies:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it how, I ended up manually clearing each cookies for each host key.

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "locale=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "datr=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "s=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "csm=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "fr=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "lu=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "c_user=");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "xs=");
```

Comment: Additionally to this, if you want to delete the cookie, you can add: android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "xs=; Max-Age=-1"); and the cookie will be deleted.

Comment: Simply doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java API. You should be able to do this by using `loadDataWithBaseUrl` (and specifying 'facebook.com' as the base URL) and removing the cookies from JavaScript.