# Remove all cookies from specific domain in web view

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to remove all the cookies from some domain, is there a way to do this?

The only method i saw is removeAllCookies.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using webview?

Comment: Yes, I am using a webView

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html), we don't have a method for removing individual cookies.
But we could use an interesting work around with `setCookie()` to clear a site's cookies. as,

> ## public abstract void setCookie (String url, String value)

> Sets a cookie for the given URL. Any existing cookie with the same host, **path and name will be replaced with the new cookie**. The cookie being set will be ignored if it is expired.

So, the solution is, As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23521188/5718968) answer, we need to manually clean up each cookie for each host key. eg:- *facebook*

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "locale=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "datr=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "s=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "csm=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "fr=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "lu=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "c_user=;Max-Age=0");
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".facebook.com", "xs=;Max-Age=0");
```

Comment: You need to set `Max-Age=0` to actualy delete the cookie otherwise you just clear its value

Answer (score 5):

First of all I can suggest you to have a look at [`CookieManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) class which manages the cookies used by WebView. There was a method `removeAllCookie()` for clearing the cookies but It was deprecated in API level 21, So instead of this you can use [`removeAllCookeis(callback)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeAllCookies(android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E)) method. You can pass `null` as the callback if you don't need to know when the operation completes or whether any cookie were removed, and in this case it is safe to call the method from a thread without a Looper.

To clear cookies in lollipop or more you can use

```java
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
```

and in rest

```java
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
cookieSyncMngr.sync();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Let'sRefactor` and `AnT` answers were helpful to find final solution for me. So basically we need to clean every cookie, one by one. But for me just setting `"value="` or `"value=; Domain=my.domain.com"` was not working. I guess it is a problem of the page I was loading, on which I had no control (it was printing crash stack trace on reading the cookies). So for me final solution was to remove cookies, not empty them. Of course we don't have any API for deleting particular cookie, but we can use parameter of  `'Set-Cookie'` HTTP response header format for Max-Age. My final code looks like this (Kotlin, in production code I have strings in constants of course ;) ):

```
val domain = myPageUri.host
CookieManager.getInstance().apply {
   getCookie(domain)
      .split("; ")
      .filter { it.isNotNullOrBlank() }
      .forEach {
         val newCookieValue = it.substringBefore("=") + "=; Max-Age=-1"
         setCookie(domain, newCookieValue)
      }
}
```

`substringBefore(character: String)` is just our extension function on `String` to return substring from start to first occurrence of `character`.

Comment: in my case it doesn't work unless I also specify proper `; Path=<path>` in the value, which you can't obtain using `CookieManager`, you could intercept the request using `WebViewClient` but it doesn't make sense in my case, so I'm probably going to remove the cookie for all possible paths: `url.toHttpUrl().encodedPathSegments.scan("/") { prefix, segment -> "$prefix$segment/" }`

Comment: I added my code https://stackoverflow.com/a/75928902/1916449

Answer (score 2):

@Let'sRefactor's answer has the right direction but not actually works because as the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html?hl=ru#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E)) states, we have to use the 'Set-Cookie' HTTP response header format:

> **value** - **String**: the cookie as a string, using the format of the 'Set-Cookie' HTTP response header

I have write the following code to remove cookies from any specific domain:

```
public static void deleteCookies(String url) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    try {
        String domainName = Utils.getDomainName(url);
        String cookiesString = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
        String[] cookies = cookiesString.split("; ");
        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(cookie))
                continue;
            int equalCharIndex = cookie.indexOf('=');
            if (equalCharIndex == -1)
                continue;
            String cookieString = cookie.substring(0, equalCharIndex) + '='
                    + "; Domain=" + domainName;
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookieString);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Message", e);
    }
}
```

And the following code to get domain without subdomain:

```
public static String getDomainName(@NotNull String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    domain = domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
    try {
        //Try to get the domain without subdomain. Ex: mobile.twitter.com would returns twitter.com
        //Note: InternetDomainName is from Guava library
        return InternetDomainName.from(domain).topPrivateDomain().toString();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("getDomainName()", "Illegal url");
    }
    return domain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't work for me, because they didn't set the correct path for the cookie.

What seems to work for me:

```kotlin
import android.webkit.CookieManager
import okhttp3.HttpUrl.Companion.toHttpUrl

fun CookieManager.removeCookies(url: String) {
    val cookies = getCookie(url) ?: return

    // Android SDK will not tell us what path was used to set the cookie, so we remove the cookie for all possible paths
    val paths = url.toHttpUrl().encodedPathSegments.scan("/") { prefix, segment -> "$prefix$segment/" }

    val keys = cookies.split(";")
            .map { it.substringBefore("=", missingDelimiterValue = "").trim() }
            .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
            .distinct()

    keys.forEach { key ->
        paths.forEach {
            // Max-Age effectively removes the cookie
            setCookie(url, "$key=; Path=$it; Max-Age=-1")
        }
    }
}
```