# Where are webview data physically stored and how to physically remove them

Tags: android, webview

When using a webview, where is its data (cookies, preferences, cache, etc) physically stored on the device?

I guess they are stored into internal app storage, but where exactly? and what kind of files are there?

In case I want to manually remove them, how to do this?

Comment: Please, ask more concrete question? What do you mean under "data in webview" ?

Comment: Meybe this link will help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390590/remove-all-cookies-from-specific-domain-in-web-view)