# Remove specific Android WebView cookies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

Can't remove all cookies for specific domain but part.
I tried to remove specific android webView cookies with the help of [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390590/remove-all-cookies-from-specific-domain-in-web-view) by method

```
cookieManager.setCookie(domain, "$key=; Path=$it; Max-Age=-1")
```

and some of them stays.

I set empty value for every key on every path but unfortunately the approach removes only part of cookies. Is it possible to remove all of them for specific domain?

Full code of implementation

```
val paths = url.toHttpUrl().encodedPathSegments.scan("/") { prefix, segment -> "$prefix$segment/" }
val keys = cookieManager.getCookiesKeys(domain) ?: return

keys.forEach { key ->
    paths.forEach {
        cookieManager.setCookie(domain, "$key=; Path=$it; Max-Age=-1")
    }
}
```

getCookiesKeys method

```
private fun CookieManager.getCookiesKeys(url: String): List<String>? {
        return getCookie(url)?.split(";")
            ?.map { it.substringBefore("=", missingDelimiterValue = "").trim() }
            ?.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
            ?.distinct()
    }
```